# Laplace transform of $f'(t)/t$

Tags: laplace-transform

A question regarding the computation of $\mathcal{L}_s[f'(t)/t]$, where $f(t)$ is a differentiable function, was asked few hours ago. Unfortunately, this question was voluntarily deleted by the OP.

I finally decided to answer this question just for mere curiosity. Firstly, I noted that, from the definition of *Laplace transform* of a function $f'(t)$:

$$ G(s) = \mathcal{L}_sf'(t) = \int^\infty_0 f'(t) e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t,$$

we can integrate this function of $s$ with respect to $s$ to have:

$$\int G(s)\mathrm{d}s = -\int^\infty_0 \frac{f'(t)}{t}e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t - K = - \mathcal{L}[f'(t)/t]-K,$$

where $K$ is a constant of integration. But, since $G(s)  = s F(s)-f(0)$, where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, we ultimately come up with:

> $$\color{blue}{ \mathcal{L}_s[f'(t)/t]= C - \int sF(s) \mathrm{d}s+sf(0) }$$

where $C$ is a new constant of integration.

Then, I got two questions out of this:

- Is the value of $C$ undetermined? Can I set it to $0$? Otherwise, how can I determine it?
- Is it safe to integrate with respect to $t$ when the limits of integration contain $t=0$?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: _Is it safe to inegrate with respect to t when the limits of integration contain t=0?_ It is only safe if $\lim_{t \to 0}(f′(t)/t)$ exists. Nice question by the way.

Comment: I told the OP that he should of added more details and working out for this question (rep score>300). Then he deleted :/. I thought it was also interesting, but wanted him to put more effort in :). I feel slightly bad now..great catch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @i.ozturk. Chinny84: yes, it was a very interesting question so I was waiting for the user to re-open it; unfortunately he didn't. Nevertheless you did well asking him to show more effort. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First call:

$$ G(u) = \mathcal{L}_uf'(t) = \int^\infty_0 f'(t) e^{-ut} \, \mathrm{d}t,$$

Integrate respect to $u$ from $0$ to $s$:

$$\int_0^s G(u)\mathrm{d}u = \int^\infty_0 \int_0^s f'(t)e^{-ut} \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}t$$ 
$$=\int^\infty_0 \frac{f'(t)}{t}[1-e^{-st}] \, \mathrm{d}t=- \mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f'(t)}{t}\right]+\int^\infty_0 \frac{f'(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Replacing $G(u)  = u F(u)-f(0)$:

$$\int_0^s  (uF(u)-f(0))du=- \mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f'(t)}{t}\right]+\int^\infty_0 \frac{f'(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Leads to:

$$\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f'(t)}{t}\right]=\int_0^s  (f(0)-uF(u))du+\int^\infty_0 \frac{f'(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f'(t)}{t}\right]=sf(0)-\int_0^s  uF(u)du+\int^\infty_0 \frac{f'(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: I see... but what are the underlying reasons that lead you to integrate $G(u)$ from $u=0$ to $u=s$? Is it the fundamental theorem of calculus, maybe?

Comment: Actually I make the integral definite in order to find the constants.

Comment: @Dmoreno and the work of finding the conditions of the integral of $\frac{f'(t)}{t}$ is still open.

Comment: Ok, I guess this resembles the way of solving initial value problems like $y' = F(t,y)$, when integratig from $t= 0$ to $t=t$ and from $y=y(t_0)$ to $y = y(t)$ for $y$. Regarding the conditions for the improper integral, I assume $\int^{\infty}_0 f'(t) / t \, dt$ should converge. Am I right?

Comment: @Dmoreno yes, but I don't know which conditions over $f$ must be accomplished